# Global planner with taking into account the robot footprint

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was wondering if it exists a *global planner* which takes into account the robot's footprint and also can be an alternative to the [navfn global_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner)?

Thanks a lot,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296406/global-planner-with-taking-into-account-the-robot-footprint/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The global planner of the navigation stack makes use of a costmap to make its global plan, provided by the [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?distro=melodic) plugin. You can change the parameters that are provided to costmap_2d to take the footprint of the robot into account, by either passing the `robot_radius` or `robot_footprint` parameter to the move_base_node when you launch it.

You can see how this could be done by taking a look at the [turtlebot_navigation](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation) package, specifically how parameters are passed to the move_base_node in the [move_base.launch.xml](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml#L16-L19) file.

In this package, the `robot_radius` parameter is set in the [costmap_common_parameters.yaml](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/param/costmap_common_params.yaml#L4) file.

---

Originally posted by [nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34948/nathan/) with karma: 111 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thanks a lot @nathan and sorry for late answer, I was trying your proposition. Actually, in my case, the [global costmap](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) does not take into account the `FootPrint` when I define it as a `Polygone` but it takes it into account when I define it as a `Circle`.

**Comment by [bageltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27940/bageltz/) on 2019-10-30**:
If I understand correctly- for simplicity and efficiency reasons, default global planner assumes the robot is circular and generates the global plan in configuration space. By that, it adds the radius buffer along all the static/dynamic obstacles, and treat the robot as a single point object in the planning algorithm. That's why it seems to only honor circular footprint instead of a polygon one.